# .bash_aliases file creates error output when opening terminal

Tags: linux, bash, linux-mint

Trying to figure out why when `.bash_aliases` file was created that it now adds an error output when opening new terminal window. Aliases inside file work fine but I don't want to have the error message generated every time I open a terminal. It should be noted that I created the `.bash_aliases` file since it was previously not generated.

Below is the `.bash_aliases` file

```
/*These are my own Aliases
  Author:Jose Estrada
*/
alias Rpi='ssh -X pi@169.254.11.26'
```

Blow is the error message

```
bash: /*These: No such file or directory
Failed to import the site module
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.4/site.py", line 586, in <module>
    main()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.4/site.py", line 572, in main
    known_paths = addusersitepackages(known_paths)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.4/site.py", line 287, in addusersitepackages
    user_site = getusersitepackages()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.4/site.py", line 263, in getusersitepackages
    user_base = getuserbase() # this will also set USER_BASE
  File "/usr/lib/python3.4/site.py", line 253, in getuserbase
    USER_BASE = get_config_var('userbase')
  File "/usr/lib/python3.4/sysconfig.py", line 597, in get_config_var
    return get_config_vars().get(name)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.4/sysconfig.py", line 540, in get_config_vars
    _init_posix(_CONFIG_VARS)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.4/sysconfig.py", line 412, in _init_posix
    from _sysconfigdata import build_time_vars
  File "/usr/lib/python3.4/_sysconfigdata.py", line 6, in <module>
    from _sysconfigdata_m import *
ImportError: No module named '_sysconfigdata_m'
bash: Arduino/: Is a directory
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

bash scripts does not have C syntax for comments.
Instead of marking comments with /* */ you should start comment rows with
#

Comment: Thank you! I feel like an idiot now. I have been writing C programs for my Raspberry Pi for the past few days that I completely forgot about that..